# C++ Move Semantics vs Copy Constructor and Assignment Operator in relation to Smart Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, smart-pointers, move-semantics

I'm trying to figure out when to use move semantics and when to use a copy constructor and assignment operator as a rule of thumb. The type of pointer you use (if any) in your class seems to be affected by this answer, so I have included this.

**No pointers** - Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048644/move-semantics-for-pod-ish-types) answer, if you have a POD class with primitive types like int and string, you don't need to write custom move or copy constructors and operators.

**unique-ptr** - Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890215/proper-implementation-of-copy-constructor-and-equals-operator-on-a-class-with-sm) answer, when using move semantics, then unique_ptr is a better fit over shared_ptr as there can only be one unique_ptr to the resource.

**shared_ptr** - Equally, if using copy semantics, shared_ptr seems the way to go. There can be multiple copies of the object, so having a shared pointer to the resource makes sense to me. However, unique_ptr is generally preferred to shared_ptr so avoid this option if you can.

But:

1. When should I use move semantics?
2. When should I use copy semantics?
3. Should I ever use both?
4. Should I ever use none and rely on the default copy constructor and assignment operator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the name indicates, use `unique_ptr` when there must exist exactly one owner to a resource. The copy constructor of `unique_ptr` is disabled, which means it is impossible for two instances of it to exist. However, it is movable... Which is fine, since that allows transfer of ownership.

Also as the name indicates, `shared_ptr` represents shared ownership of a resource. However, there is also another difference between the two smart pointers: The `Deleter` of a `unique_ptr` is part of its type signature, but it is not part of the type signature of `shared_ptr`. That is because `shared_ptr` uses "type erasure" to "erase the type" of the deleter. Also note that `shared_ptr` can also be moved to transfer ownership (like `unique_ptr`.)

*When should I use move semantics?*

Although `shared_ptr` can be copied, you may want to move them anyways when you are making a transfer of ownership (as opposed to creating a new reference). You're obligated to use move semantics for `unique_ptr`, since ownership must be unique.

*When should I use copy semantics?*

In the case of smart pointers, you should use copying to increase the reference count of `shared_ptr`s. (If you're unfamiliar with the concept of a reference count, research reference counted garbage collection.)

*Should I ever use both?*

Yes. As mentioned above, `shared_ptr` can be both copied and moved. Copying denotes incrementing the reference count, while moving only indicates a transfer of ownership (the reference count stays the same.)

*Should I ever use none and rely on the default copy constructor and assignment operator?*

When you want to make a member-by-member copy of an object.

Answer (score 5):

1. When should I use move semantics?

   I presume by this you mean, "When should I give my class a move constructor?" The answer is whenever moving objects of this type is useful and the default move constructor doesn't do the job correctly. Moving is useful when there is some benefit to transferring resources from one object to another. For example, moving is useful to `std::string` because it allows objects to be copied from temporaries without having to reallocate and copy their internal resources and instead by simply moving the resource from one to the other. Many types would benefit from this. On the other hand, moving is useful to `std::unique_ptr` because it is the only way to pass a `std::unique_ptr` around by value without violating its "unique ownership".
2. When should I use copy semantics?

   Again, I presume by this you mean, "When should I give my class a copy constructor?" Whenever you need to be able to make copies of an object, where internal resources are copied between them, and the default copy constructor doesn't do the job correctly. Copying is useful for almost any type, except those like `std::unique_ptr` that must enforce unique ownership over an internal resource.
3. Should I ever use both?

   Your classes should provide both copy and move semantics most of the time. The most common classes should be both copyable and moveable. Being copyable provides the standard semantics of passing around an object by value. Being moveable allows the optimisation that can be gained when passing around a temporary object by value. Whether this means having to provide a copy or move constructor depends on whether the default constructors do the appropriate things.
4. Should I ever use none and rely on the default copy constructor and assignment operator?

   The default copy and move constructors just do a copy or move of each member of the class respectively. If this behaviour is appropriate for copying and moving your class, that's great. Most of the time, this should be good enough. For example, if I have a class that contains a `std::string`, the default copy constructor will copy the string over, and the default move constructor will move the string's resources to the new object - both do the appropriate job. If your class contains a `std::unique_ptr`, copying will simply not work, and your class will only be moveable. That may be what you want, or you may want to implement a copy constructor that performs a deep copy of the resource. The most important case in which you should implement copy/move constructors is when your class performs resource management itself (using `new` and `delete`, for example). If that's the case, the default constructors will almost never be doing a good job of managing those resources.

Everything here applies similarly to the assignment operator.